# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: react-native, native-base

Hi I am starting to use react native, but I have problem using nativebase with expo.
When using the code in the documentation this error appears:
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or class / function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
Check the render method of 'App'
[Here the error] (https://ibb.co/nQpBqYv)

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo-app-loading';
import { Container, Text } from 'native-base';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isReady: false,
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      Roboto: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
      Roboto_medium: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
      ...Ionicons.font,
    });
    this.setState({ isReady: true });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isReady) {
      return <AppLoading />;
    }

    return (
      <Container>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `<AppLoading />`?

Comment: @ShivamJha  I'm not really sure, it's an example from the nativebase documentation [https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/GetStarted.html ]

Comment: So, you have not defined `<AppLoading />`? That's why it is showing error? Make a component named `<AppLoading />` containing just one line of `<Text>`. since you have not defined it, it is `undefined`, and hence the error

Comment: Replace line 2 with this >>>> import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';

Comment: @AlishGiri that was

Comment: Gald to help. Please upvote the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @AlishGiri Do you want to publish the answer or do I publish it?
Thanks to you cheers

Comment: I have left the answer @BovverBoy

Comment: @AlishGiriHi, excuse me, can I ask you one more question? I can't send you a message here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with the nativebase. You actually need to correct the following import statement,

```
import { AppLoading } from 'expo-app-loading';
```

to the following,

```
 import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
```

Comment: This also worked for an issue I had with custom fonts with Expo. Thanks!