# after updating expo: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

After I updated my Expo SDK from 39 to 42, I got following error when trying to launch the app:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.
>
> This error is located at:
> in App (created by ExpoRoot)
> in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
> in RCTView (at View.js:34)
> in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
> in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

From the bug report I conclude that the error is located in my App.js file, even tho I havent changed anything beside upgrading my expo version.

App.js:

```
//Automatic imports
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

//My imports
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import {AppLoading} from 'expo';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';


//import other screens
import NavigationContainer from './navigation/NavigationContainer';

//import Reducers
import authReducer from './store/reducers/auth';
import pigeonReducer from './store/reducers/pigeon';
import badgesReducer from './store/reducers/badges';
import languagesReducer from './store/reducers/language';

//imports related to firebase
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import ApiKeys from "./constants/ApiKeys";

//Loading Fonts, returns promise
const fetchFonts = () => {
  return Font.loadAsync({
    'Magnus' : require('./assets/fonts/MagnusText.ttf'),
    'AmaticBold' : require('./assets/fonts/Amatic-Bold.ttf'),
    'AmaticRegular' : require('./assets/fonts/AmaticSC-Regular.ttf'),
    'SEASRN' : require('./assets/fonts/SEASRN.ttf'),
    'Otto' : require('./assets/fonts/Otto.ttf'),
    'Gwibble' : require('./assets/fonts/GWIBBLE.ttf'),
    'GTA' : require('./assets/fonts/pricedown.otf')
  });
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  myPigeons: pigeonReducer,
  myBadges: badgesReducer,
  myLanguage: languagesReducer
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));


export default function App() {
  //firebase project initialisation
  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(ApiKeys);
    //console.log("DB INITIALISED"); FIRING IF DATABASE INITIALISED
  };

  const [dataLoaded, setDataLoaded] = useState(false); //are fonts loaded?

  if(!dataLoaded){ //will go into if clause because fonts are not loaded
    return(
      <AppLoading 
        startAsync={fetchFonts} 
        onFinish={() => setDataLoaded(true)}
        onError={(err) => console.log(err)}
      />
    )
  }
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer/>
    </Provider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I know there were several people experiencing the same error, but there are much answers to their problems which dont work for me, maybe somebody has any idea how to fix mine.
Incase you need other code samples from my project, let me know it and I will update this question.

Comment: 99% of the time this error means you're importing `Xyz` from somewhere but it actually doesn't exist as export. Thus when you try and do `<Xyz ... />` you'll get the error you see. For instance you have `import {AppLoading} from 'expo';` Just try putting `console.log(AppLoading);` directly after your import lines and check if it's an actual component.

Comment: @ChrisG perfect approach, I got undefined from it. Updated this package and imported it correctly and I fixed it. 

If you want, make a answer to this post and I give you the green hook for it.

Comment: I would, but this is definitely a duplicate. This is a very common error.

Comment: Found pretty much an exact dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66924778/element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-for-built-in-components-or-class-fu

Comment: @ChrisG the error log is the same but the solution I applied is a different one, the one you send in here didnt work for me. I also saw it but decided to post mine as a question anyways because the other fixes applied didnt help me before.

Comment: @ChrisG What helped me was your ```console.log(AppLoading)``` and seeing that I get an ```undefined``` back. After that I checked the Module out on the Expo Docs and saw that it is imported differently and now you need to type in ```import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';``` also I needed of course to install it with ```npm``` first, thats how I fixed it :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of all that. One problem with the duplicates is that the people who post answers are all referring to very specific libraries and imports, instead of providing the actual root cause of the problem i.e. one of the imports is undefined. So I'm actually going to post an answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

99% of the time this error means you're importing `Xyz` from somewhere but it actually doesn't exist as export.

Thus when you try and do `<Xyz ... />` in your JSX you'll get the error, which I'll reproduce here:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: **undefined**. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

(emphasis mine)

`undefined` is the key here, for instance you have

```
import {AppLoading} from 'expo';
```

The line according to the current docs however is

```
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
```

To debug this, check imported components by simply logging them:

```
console.log(AppLoading);
```

You'll quickly find the import that is `undefined`, which is what causes the error.

Comment: Thanks. It is 'expo-app-loading' after I upgraded to 41 Expo version